# Objective C read file wrong encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, encoding

Hi all I have a problem when I download file from internet from which I need to mine some data. I open it and try to buffer it, but it gives me wrong chars because this file is in Czech... 
My code:

```
- (void) sync {

    NSString * path = @"/Users/syky/Documents/stats.csv";
    NSFileHandle * fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSData * buffer = nil;
    while ((buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1024])) {
    //do something with the buffer

    NSString * s = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:buffer encoding:nil];
    NSLog(s);
    break;

}
```

No matter which encoding I choose I always get broken chars such as

```
"Poø.";"Jméno"
```

I need to get:

```
"Příjmení";"Jméno"
```

This file is originaly generated by Microsoft Excel such as *.csv export file...
When I try to open this file by any MAC OS X Text editor I get broken chars as well, but when I open it on other Windows based maschine with Microsoft Excel it works just fine...

Thank you for your help

Solution:

```
- (void) sync {

    NSString * path = @"/Users/syky/Documents/stats.csv";
    NSFileHandle * fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSData * buffer = nil;
    while ((buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1024])) {

    NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsLatin2);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:encoding];

    NSLog(string);

    break;

}
```

Comment: You're passing `nil` for the `encoding` parameter? Really?

Comment: + (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error

Comment: @trudyscousin if you could read little bit more I am saying: No matter which encoding I choose I always get broken chars such as... With nil I get closest result!!!

Comment: @TomasSykora Yes, but nil, or 0, isn't a valid encoding. I'm working on an answer for you.

Comment: @trudyscousin Thank you! I have tried every possible encoding I could find and none of it worked...

Comment: @trudyscousin When I use NSISOLatin2StringEncoding I get ř correctly but š and ž are broken ...

Comment: @TomasSykora Try the kCFStringEncodingMacCentralEurRoman as I described in my answer. Do let us know if that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm not a Czech speaker. Second, I think "use UTF-8" is akin to saying "throw a barrel at it." It's heavy-handed in the same way.

From what I've researched, you could use ISO Latin 2 or Apple's Central European Roman encoding. You'll find the former represented among `NSStringEncoding`s, but not the latter, so look to Core Foundation's support:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingMacCentralEurRoman);
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:encoding];
```

Otherwise, you could (and probably already have, from what you've said) use:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSISOLatin2StringEncoding];
```

I'm really curious to see if using `CFStringEncoding` encodings improves your situation.

EDIT:

If your source was generated by Microsoft Excel, perhaps `kCFStringEncodingWindowsLatin2` will work instead of `kCFStringEncodingMacCentralEurRoman`. Like before, you'll need to convert it using CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding.

There's one other approach you might want to try. Since `CFStringRef` is "toll-bridged" to `NSString` (and so is `CFDataRef` to `NSData`), perhaps working entirely in Core Foundation might work:

```
CFStringRef stringRef = CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef)buffer, kCFStringEncodingMacCentralEurRoman);
NSString *string = (NSString *)stringRef;
```

In this case, don't forget that `stringRef` has to be released.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Comment: WOW, it did not worked out. But it did something... "PoÝ.";"Jmťno" Something completely different than I expected...

Comment: @TomasSykora Aw, nuts. Still your problem interests me, and I'll see what else I can find. KOI-8 L2 encoding was mentioned in my reading, but I can't see that Apple supports it.

Comment: The file can be accessed from this link: http://www.baseball.cz/modules.php?op=modload&name=liga&file=index&do=statx&akce=219&pda=2&admina=op=modload&name=liga&file=index&pda=2&admina=&akce=219&do=statx&vypis=1&mode=Export+do+Excelu&xco=palka&xtyp=0&xzid=0

Comment: @TomasSykora See my edit; meanwhile, I'll check out your file.