# iOS how to decoding a text that is ISO6937 encoded?

Tags: ios, encoding, character-encoding

I'm implementing an TV parser software.

When in Czech, I found that the EPG is encoded by **ISO6937**.

I used the following API to decode and switch to `NSString`.

```
- (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)len encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

but I can't find the encoding ENUM.
`CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingISOLatin2)` is not correct.

Is anyone can help me?

Comment: Hmmm, that looks like a tough one.  You might need to use a different library to convert ISO6937 to UTF-8 before it can be used.

Comment: what you mean by "not correct"? isn't it working or does it give error?

Comment: @x4h1d I am pretty sure it means that `kCFStringEncodingISOLatin2` is not the encoding he is looking for (`ISO-6937`)

Comment: @x4h1d, I can get a string, but the content will have some mistakes.
for example, the 0xcf character is used as accent, but it will display as a char.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If the encoding, you mentioned, is not working try these following encoding

```
CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingMacCentralEurRoman)
```

or

```
NSISOLatin2StringEncoding
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581447/objective-c-read-file-wrong-encoding) post.

## Edit

Here is the list of encoding supported on iOS8.3. Try responsibly.

```
NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,          /* kCFStringEncodingDOSJapanese */
NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,    /* Cyrillic; same as AdobeStandardCyrillic */
NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,    /* WinLatin1 */
NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,    /* Greek */
NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,    /* Turkish */
NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,    /* WinLatin2 */
NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,        /* ISO 2022 Japanese encoding for e-mail */
NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,

NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */

NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,       /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,                   
NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
```

Comment: Neither of those are ISO-6937, are they.